# Bitwise ops - The relationship between $a$, $b$, $a \wedge b$, $a \vee b$ and $a \oplus b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary, computer-arithmetic

In computer programming, the term *bitwise operation* is used to denote the use of boolean operators (and $\wedge$, or $\vee$, exclusive or $\oplus$) on corresponding bits of two numbers. Bits, in this case, refers to the digits of the numbers written in base 2.

For example, with $a = 134 = 10000110_2$ and $b = 93 = 01011101_2$, we have:

$$a \wedge b = 00000100_2 = 4$$
$$a \vee b = 11011111_2 = 223$$
$$a \oplus b = 11011011_2 = 219$$

I am curious if there are **any meaningful relationships** between these five values? Clearly, $a \wedge b$ is smaller than or equal to both $a$ and $b$, and likewise $a \vee b$ is larger than or equal to both $a$ and $b$. Also, if $a \wedge b$ is odd, then both $a$ and $b$ are odd.

But these are all pretty trivial. One more interesting note is that if $b = a-1$, then $a \wedge b = 0$ iff $a$ is a power of 2, but that is instead a very special case.

**Can we do better?** I am especially interested in what we can know about the numbers $a$ and $b$ from these three other values, or if there's a way to express $\max(a,b)$ from these numbers or something like that. :)

(Programmers might better recognize the "usual" notations $\&$ for and, $|$ for or, and $\wedge$ for exclusive or).

Comment: `\vee` gives you $\vee$.

Comment: @Hayden Agreed, but that's not a caret, it's up-side down.

Comment: Then you mean `\wedge` for $\wedge$? (but this is not typically used for exclusive or ($\oplus$ is), though perhaps the usage differs for the programming community.)

Comment: Or do you mean a literal ^?

Comment: Ah, wedge seems to be correct, thanks. Yes, it's the common notation in programming. I was unsure whether to go with that or with more standard mathematical notation here.

Comment: @naslundx The usual symbols are `\vee` for or ($\vee$), `\wedge` for and ($\wedge$) and `\oplus` for xor ($\oplus$) if you want to change the notation ;)

Comment: @naslundx I would guess standard mathematical notation would be helpful for people (especially when they see $\wedge$ being used in a role they're not used to), though at least you state what they mean beforehand.

Comment: All of them can be expressed in terms of either [Logical NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR) or [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke)

Answer (score 2):

There is the relationship $(a\wedge b)\oplus (a\vee b) \oplus (a\oplus b)=0$ which holds for all $a$ and $b$.

Or, equivalently, any two of $a\wedge b$, $a\vee b$, and $a\oplus b$ will produce the third upon combining with $\oplus$.

Comment: Also $a \oplus b \oplus (a\oplus b) = 0$ trivially but with an analogous property.

Comment: That's a fine one, but I was hoping for something that let's me know something about $a$ and $b$, perhaps.

Comment: I don't know if this addresses your point. But since $\wedge, \vee, \oplus$ are all commutative, their values will never let you distinguish between $a=0, b=1$; and $a=1, b=0$.